Which is the difference in notation between [], () and {}
I was looking into several mathematical formula and I came up with several questions:

What is the difference between:


$V= [x_i \mid x_i \in X, x_i \neq 0]$
$V= (x_i \mid x_i \in X, x_i \neq 0)$
$V= \{x_i \mid x_i \in X, x_i \neq 0\}$


Where did you find this notation? I've only ever seen the third.

As with anything, it depends on context.  In the context of set definitions, I would say that only (3) is valid notation.

What's $i$?  I take it that $V$ is meant to be the set of non-zero elements of $X$, but it's not clear (to me) what $i$ denotes.  In any case, only $#3$ is standard notation, I'd say.

The second one resembles the notation for an ordered n-tuple although the internal language of the construction is strange and not quite right.  The first.... a vector?  I'm going to parrot that context is everything.  The third one is the only one that is self evident (although the subindex $i$ is arbitrary and confusing).

All of these looks like they  denote a set with the given properties. But the convension is to write the third one. In all math texts you'll see sets written with the third notation.
And because you said you came across them in different formulas,my guess is that you saw the first two brackets in different places(not in set notations). For example, closed sets are written with the box brackets and open sets are written with round brackets etc.

Do you know of any examples where the first two are used? I've never seen it before at all.

I never saw them as set notations. I edited the answer. @CyclotomicField
